# UIColletionView Jumps Up On Popping Back From Another Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i have a **uicollectionviewcontroller** as **rootviewcontroller** in my navigationController. whenever i return from another controller that is pushed onto this stack. the collectionview jumps up 25pix. i have tried some tips from other questions like     **self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false**, changing **contentOffset** after collection appears but none of them work.
i have no idea what causes this problem.

[this is a sample off whats happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwWVW.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This property is applied only to view controllers that are embedded in a container such as UINavigationController

The window’s root view controller does not react to this property. The default value of this property is `UIRectEdge.all`

Setting it to `UIRectEdge.none` should resolve it

`self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None`

Comment: Make sure to pin your collection view `topAnchor` to `topLayoutGuide`. If that doesn't help, carefully examine what is causing it in the UI Debugger of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have this problem because of `tabbar.ishidden = true` and then after pop the view controller you will again set the `tabbar.ishidden = false` .

this would fix with a review in your constraint in storyboard, e.g if you have your bottom constraint to tabbar, change it to superView. this would prevent relayouting your collecitonView.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i'm not using storyboard and also collectionview in collectionviewcontroller adjust constraints automatically, i dont have access to contraints. that is possible if i turn that off. by the way it used hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true for hiding tabbar